# How can I share a common thread pool amongst objects in Perl?

Tags: multithreading, perl, oop, thread-safety, multiprocessing

I've been trying to extend the first answer at Perl Monks (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=735923) to a threaded model to no avail.  I keep getting issues with not being able to pass a coderef

In my superclass I define the threadpool as a package variable so it can be shared amongst the subclasses:

```
package Things::Generic;

my $Qwork = new Thread::Queue;
my $Qresults = new Thread::Queue;

my @pool = map { threads->create(\&worker, $Qwork, $Qresults) } 1..$MAX_THREADS;

sub worker {
    my $tid = threads->tid;
    my( $Qwork, $Qresults ) = @_;
    while( my $work = $Qwork->dequeue ) {
        my $result = $work->process_thing();
        $Qresults->enqueue( $result );
    }
    $Qresults->enqueue( undef ); ## Signal this thread is finished
}

sub enqueue {
   my $self = shift;
   $Qwork->enqueue($self);
}

sub new {
  #Blessing and stuff
}
.
.
```

Now for the subclasses.  It is guaranteed that they have a process_thing() method.

```
package Things::SpecificN;
use base qw (Things::Generic);

sub new() {
 #instantiate
}

sub do_things {
  my $self = shift;

  #enqueue self into the shared worker pool so that "process_thing" is called
  $self->enqueue();
}

sub process_thing() {
   #Do some work here
   return RESULT;
}
```

#

```
Main
my @things;

push @things, Things::Specific1->new();
push @things, Things::Specific2->new();
.
.
push @things, Things::SpecificN->new();

#Asynchronously kick off "work"
foreach my $thing (@things) {
    $thing->do_things();
}
```

My goal is to put a list of "work" on the queue.  Each thread will pull work from the queue and execute it, no matter what it.  Each Thing has it's own unique work, however the function to do the work will be guaranteed to be called "process_thing".  I just want the thread pool to grab an entry from the queue and do the "something".  I think I am describing functionality similar to Android AsyncTask.

My Perl is not high enough for Thread::Queue::Any

Comment: Take a look at `Storable` - `freeze` and `thaw` are excellent ways of moving objects around in queues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Qwork->enqueue($self);` instead of `$self->enqueue();`

Comment: "Still"? You never mentioned any complaints about code refs. In fact, your code doesn't have any problems with code refs as it does use any code refs.